# Turn off list indentation for a single \gabcsnippet{} block

Tags: lists, gregorio

For some needs, I have some `\gabcsnippet` blocks within a list-like environment (`itemize` or `enumerate`). How to skip list indentation for these blocks only? Example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{gregoriotex}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item List item
  \item List item

  % it's desirable to skip list indentation for this line.
  \gabcsnippet{(c4) Pro(h)ce(h)dá(h)mus(h) in(h) pa(h)ce.(f) (::)}

  \item List item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use the `wide` option from `enumitem`.

Comment: Thank you, but this option will affect the whole list, not a single item. Moreover, It can lead to undesired results in a two-column document.

Comment: For the unwanted results in two-column, I have no idea *a priori*. However, if it is for a single item you have the solution  to begin the list without this option, interrupt the list and start another list with this single item and the wide option, interrupt it again and start a third list without the option if there are other items.

Answer (score 1):

The `adjustbox` package defines a command `\adjustbox` with two arguments, the adjustments and the contents. Various adjustments are possible, one of which is the margin, defined as left/bottom/right/top values.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gregoriotex}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\noindent abc
\begin{itemize}
  \item List item
  \item List item

  % it's desirable to skip list indentation for this line.
  % margins: left bottom right top
  \adjustbox{margin=-26pt 0ex 0ex 0ex}{\gabcsnippet{(c4) Pro(h)ce(h)dá(h)mus(h) in(h) pa(h)ce.(f) (::)}}

  \item List item
  
  % further to the left and a bit of top margin
  \adjustbox{margin=-28pt 0ex 0ex 2ex}{\gabcsnippet{(c4) Pro(h)ce(h)dá(h)mus(h) in(h) pa(h)ce.(f) (::)}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]